# Need to convert a list into set, but It needs to stay in alphabetical order

Tags: list, set, alphabetical

THis is how my code looks like:

```
site1 = ["breakfast", "view", "beach", "hospitality", "breakfast", "clean", "view"]
site2 = ["dinner", "view", "unfriendly", "pool", "clean", "pool"]


 site1_no_dupes = []
    for i in site1:
        if i not in site1_no_dupes:
            site1_no_dupes.append(i)
    site2_no_dupes = []
    for i in site2:
        if i not in site2_no_dupes:
            site2_no_dupes.append(i)
    my_final_list = site1_no_dupes + site2_no_dupes
    actual_final_list = []
    for i in my_final_list:
        if i not in actual_final_list:
            actual_final_list.append(i)
    actual_final_list2 = sorted(actual_final_list)
    actual_final_list3 = set(actual_final_list2)
    
    print(actual_final_list3)
```

When I print it it comes out likes this

```
{'pool', 'unfriendly', 'breakfast', 'hospitality', 'clean', 'view', 'beach', 'dinner'}
```

But I want it like this:

```
{'beach', 'breakfast', 'clean', 'dinner', 'hospitality', 'pool', 'unfriendly','view'}
```

I am very close because if I remove the last line it comes out like this:

```
['beach', 'breakfast', 'clean', 'dinner', 'hospitality', 'pool', 'unfriendly', 'view']
```

So the only thing I need to do here is convert it to a set while keeping it in alphabetical order, anyone know what to do? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it just in one line by first sorting the list, and turning this into a set like this:

```
actual_final_list2 = set(sorted(actual_final_list))
print(actual_final_list2)
```

your output will be:

```
{'beach', 'clean', 'unfriendly', 'view', 'breakfast', 'hospitality', 'dinner', 'pool'}
```